# Temporary files are 481 GB but hdd has only 500 GB storage

Tags: hard-drive, temporary-files

Hi Guys today I want to delete the unused files on my computer --> so i ran the in build tool.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4R5E.png)

and there i have the option to delete my temporary files but it is not possible that i have 481 GB of temporary data...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au5MP.png)

can i delete it or what should I do
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Use `Treesize` to find files that take up space.

Comment: If it is temporary files then yes you can delete the temp files as they are just that "temp" and not system critical so if Windows labels them temp, then they are safe to delete without causing the OS problems. If you want to know what these are before you delete them, then you will need to do some digging to find them using some tool, etc.